# Kafka cannot get offsets when 1 out of 3 brokers is down

Tags: apache-kafka

I have 3 Kafka brokers running. All my topics have replication factor set to 2. When I shut down one of the brokers, Kafka cluster, to my understanding, should keep working, but for some reason it doesn't.

For example, I can't run the following script, which works normally when all brokers are alive.

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group myGroup --describe 
Note: This will not show information about old Zookeeper-based consumers. 
Error: Executing consumer group command failed due to Failed to get offsets by times in 305000ms
```

The system topic that contains the offsets (__consumer_offsets) is also properly replicated. Broker 1 is down, but there's still at least one healthy replica.

```
./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost --topic __consumer_offsets --describe
Topic:__consumer_offsets    PartitionCount:50   ReplicationFactor:2 Configs:segment.bytes=104857600,cleanup.policy=compact,compression.type=producer
    Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 0    Leader: 3   Replicas: 3,1   Isr: 3
    Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 1    Leader: 2   Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 2
    Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 2    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,3   Isr: 3,2
    Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 3    Leader: 3   Replicas: 3,2   Isr: 2,3
    Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 4    Leader: 3   Replicas: 1,3   Isr: 3
    Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 5    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,1   Isr: 2
    Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 6    Leader: 3   Replicas: 3,1   Isr: 3
    Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 7    Leader: 2   Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 2
    Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 8    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,3   Isr: 3,2
    (...)
```

Any idea why I'm getting the "Failed to get offsets" error?

Comment: Is broker 1 the one running on localhost:9092?

Comment: @pgras nope, it was executed on a different host

Comment: I've hit the same issue and I figured out it was happening for topics which had replication.factor=1, and therefore partitions which were assigned to this broker were unavailable because no other replicas could take leadership.